# sorting by value in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

This is a multidimensional array I got from Google Calendar for displaying events.

```
Array
(
[items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [status] => confirmed
                [summary] => Let's go swimming!
                [start] => Array
                    (
                        [dateTime] => 2011-12-30T09:00:00-05:00
                    )

                [end] => Array
                    (
                        [dateTime] => 2011-12-30T10:00:00-05:00
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [status] => confirmed
                [summary] => red wine
                [start] => Array
                    (
                        [dateTime] => 2011-12-28T06:00:00-05:00
                    )

                [end] => Array
                    (
                        [dateTime] => 2011-12-28T07:00:00-05:00
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [status] => confirmed
                [summary] => Christmas
                [start] => Array
                    (
                        [dateTime] => 2011-12-28T09:30:00-05:00
                    )

                [end] => Array
                    (
                        [dateTime] => 2011-12-28T10:30:00-05:00
                    )

            )
     )
)
```

I want to use PHP to sort by end[datetime]. If anyone could give me some help I would really appreciate it.  I was wondering how to do it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
usort($array['items'], function($a, $b){
    if ($a['end']['dateTime'] === $b['end']['dateTime']) return 0;
    else return ($a['end']['dateTime']  > $b['end']['dateTime']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

[usort](http://www.php.net/usort)();

In this particular case you can compare the dates as strings and get the correct answer due to the format. In some other cases, you might need other methods, like converting to unix timestamp and comparing those.

Comment: I used an anonymous function, which needs php 5.3+. See the example in the manual for other ways to specify the comparison function.

Comment: yep, works after I separated the function and called it by `usort($response['items'], 'function_name');`, thanks!

Comment: *...well this changes everything...*

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no direct way to to that. I typically do something like

```
$items=array();
foreach($mainarray['items'] as $k=>$v) $items[$v['end']['$dateTime'."-$k"]]=$v;
ksort($items);
$mainarray['items']=array_values($items);
```